# Action bar not showing :Theme.Appcompat.Light.DarkActionBar in preference activity

Tags: android

I want to use this theme in my preference activity because of the nice checkbox but my action bar isn't showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) does not extend `ActionBarActivity`, which is required for action bar to be available.

If you need a preferences screen with action bar, try to use `PreferenceFragment` inside an `ActionBarActivity` instead.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
    ...
}
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment

Comment: This sucks: i want to use the example from Android studio. When you select New -> Activity -> SettingsActivity because that should be the way to go... Why does Google not update there presents in Android studio when they update their support library!?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `PreferenceFragment` inside an `ActionBarActivity` and still want  to use your existing `PreferenceActivity` with `AppCompat` Support Library v7, you can use to use `Toolbar` and override `PreferenceActvity.setContentView()` with a customized layout

You can use `Toolbar` support while maintaining the current `PreferenceActivity` and it works well for 2.3.4 and above

```
private Toolbar mActionBar;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp_Settings);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    mActionBar.setTitle(getTitle());

    //other things to create/init 
}


public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    ViewGroup contentView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
        R.layout.settings_activity, new LinearLayout(this), false);

    mActionBar = (Toolbar) contentView.findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
    mActionBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    ViewGroup contentWrapper = (ViewGroup) contentView.findViewById(R.id.content_wrapper);
    LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(layoutResID, contentWrapper, true);

    getWindow().setContentView(contentView);
}
```

settings_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.Settings" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.Toolbar</item>
</style>


<style name="Widget.Toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="navigationIcon">?attr/homeAsUpIndicator</item>
</style>
```